# C# connect to MySQL and read data

Tags: c#, mysql, database, sqldatareader

So I have this website that people can shop online, but I want to make a software that will read the MySQL database for new orders and when a new order is placed, the software should display the order in some sort of a list. I am using wordpress for this website and there is a button to mark the order as completed, so i also want to have that little button in my program. Any help from where I should be starting ? Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for a freelance developer to work with this project, Then this is the wrong place for that

Comment: Simple help - Do some actual research. Pick your favorite search engine, then go nuts.

Comment: You seem to have a very vague understanding of your problem. I think you need to look in to C# and MySQL and understand what they are / what they do - and then go on to looking at tutorials specific to your needs

Answer (score 0):

Kindly do some research work before ask Any question. This may help u.

```
 MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
 string myConnectionString;

 myConnectionString = "server=xxxx;uid=xxx;" +     
 "pwd=xxxx;database=xxx;";
 try
 {
     conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
     conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
     conn.Open();
 }
 catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
```